# Burn the [patterns] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

As is evident from its empty tag-wiki, the tag [patterns](/questions/tagged/patterns) does not convey much info on its own.

- Questions tagged with it usually refer to either [design-patterns](/questions/tagged/design-patterns) or [pattern-matching](/questions/tagged/pattern-matching).
- There are a couple of other minor [xxxx-pattern](/questions/tagged/xxxx-pattern) tags specific to certain frameworks/libraries.

At the moment, there are **1035** questions (its synonymous tags have >15K).
Should we (may I) start re-tagging them and burn the [patterns](/questions/tagged/patterns) tag?...

Comment: Get to it, man.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Roger that. :-) Right now cleaning-up the [tag:recognition] tag. Will start with [tag:patterns] after this. Just thought of asking for confirmation first, since this is my first attempt at tag cleanup/burning. Thank You.

Comment: Pattern is already synonymized to design-pattern, so I'm just going to go ahead and synonymize patterns also.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok. So next we can just properly re-tag questions which mean [tag:patern-matching] but are marked with [tag:patterns]. Right?...

Comment: They're gonna be hard to find, now that I synonymized. :)

Comment: If you find any that don't belong, feel free to remove the tag.

Comment: [Some](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdesign-patterns%5D+%22pattern+matching%22) [candidates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns+matching) for tag fixing (there may be some overlap between those).